# Swift: Is there any way to save a signature into a String of points?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, signature, points

I'd like to learn how I can save an user's signature (with pencil -ipad pro - or finger) into a String of points. Each point should be: X, Y, pressure, time. It's like a biometric signature.

Should I user UIImageView or CanvasView?

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what do you mean by CanvasView.

You can use UITouch class properties like force and maximumPossibleForce that lets the app detect and respond to touch pressure.

See [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Adopting3DTouchOniPhone/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016543-CH1-SW1) Apple link for understanding 3D Touch.

Also, [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TouchCanvas/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016561) sample code by Apple, uses force information to change line thickness.

By implementing: touchesBegan, touchesMoved, touchesEnded and touchesCancelled you should be able to get the coordinates of touches which you can couple with force info from 3D touch and time stamp from NSDate to capture signatures as per your requirement.

Comment: I meant to get a handwritten signature into a Points string

Comment: @oskarko: The sample code attached has the similar canvas view like functionality where the user draws handwritten signature. You can save the co-ordinates and force info in your desired format.